# Measure the time it takes for Java class to run

Tags: java

Is it possible to start a timer in a Java class, so that I may measure the time it takes for its task?

I tried with

```
Date d2 = (Date) session.getAttribute("date2");
Date d1 = new Date();

long seconds = (d2.getTime()-d1.getTime())/1000;
System.out.println("time: " + seconds);

Date dates = new Date();                
session.setAttribute("date2", dates);
```

But it's giving me some wierd negative numbers, that I cannot make sense off.

Comment: d1 is always greater than d2 as it is the current time. so it should be d1.getTime() - d2.getTime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's giving me some wierd negative numbers

`d2` is going to be before `d1`:

- `d2` was "now" the last time the method was called in this session
- `d1` is "now" *this* time the method was called.

As such, `d2.getTime() < d1.getTime()`.

Reverse the order of the subtraction.